# Group matrix filled with similarity scores into buckets

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, data-science, computer-science

Let's say we have n strings in `strs`. You compare all the strings together, full permutation (n^2) and build an nxn matrix where each cell is the similarity score between 2 strings (i, j).

How do I take this a step further and group them into buckets? Practically, I'm expecting these strings to be similar/fall into a bucket -- but there's a chance some new ones might not, so I want to find the closest resemblance or recalculate the buckets.

```
public Map<String, List<String>> bucketIt(String[] strs) {
    int[][] arr = new int[strs.length][strs.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < strs.length; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = getSimilarityScore(strs[i], strs[j]);
        }
    }

    // How do I take the scores out of arr[][] and group the strings of strs into buckets.
}
```

I plan to use [tdebatty/java-string-similarity](https://github.com/tdebatty/java-string-similarity) to calculate the scores. A solution which uses a threshold value for all buckets is also acceptable.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **your** ideas / findings.

Comment: So after calculating the pairwise similarity do you want to [cluster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use a HashTable type of approach where you store similar strings (i.e. having scores in the range [score - bucket_size, score + bucket_size) ) in the same bucket.

The buckets would just be an array of (linked) lists of all strings having similar scores as defined above.

Ideally you would want to keep the lists in the buckets small and use an exponential grow algorithm to increase the number of buckets as needed. When you grow you would rehash your table.

Comment: I like this solution. It's simple and I think it'll work.